# How to edit Magento 2.3.2 items.phtml

Tags: magento2

I am trying to edit order email template to fit my needs. However I am not able to edit the last part where the order items, quantity and price are. I want to have something like what you are seeing on the image below. As you I want Item name only on the left, followed by SKU number, 3rd column quantity and last column item/s price. I've tried to make direct edits to items.phtml but I am not able to understand how to have this result. [image: Order email template]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order email template's item section coming from this file in default Magento

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml

You can override this template file here in your custom theme

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml

You can change content here based on your requirement.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I was looking at the wrong place the entire time. Thank you

Comment: You're most welcome buddy. :)